# How to go to next page if records exist?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm doing a paging calculation to paging my records. Is the typical calculation that we found in every web site:

```
totalPage = (int) Math.Ceiling((double) TotalRecords / PageSize);
```

What i want to do now is a paging On-Demand. I mean 10 by 10 (for example)

In my grid i don't need to show all the pages calculated as i said before. 
I just want to show a "next button" and a "previous button"

How can i do that? i'm using sql server and c#

This is my current code:

```
var result = new Utils.PagedResult<T>
{
    CurrentPage = page,
    PageSize = pageSize
    Total = query.Count()
};
     result.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(result.Total / (double)pageSize);
     result.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(result.Total / (double)pageSize);
     result.PreviousPage = page > 1 ? "Yes" : "No";
     result.NextPage = page < result.TotalPages ? "Yes" : "No";
     var pageCount = (double)result.Total / pageSize;
     result.PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(pageCount);

     var skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with 3 separate programming languages?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons edited

Comment: @emsimpson92 edited

Answer (score 0):

if you are using entity framework you have to add this line:

```
contextObject.Skip(skip).Take(result.PageSize).ToList();
```